# Does libtorrent support http web seed with digest authentication?

Tags: c++, http, digest-authentication, libtorrent

I implement a bittorrent client using libtorrent. but I meet a problem. I have a http file server as the web seed. The server just support digest authentication for http request. and Libtorrent support basic auth by default. Does it have any way to make libtorrent to support digest auth? It would be nice to give an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does not look like it provides any hooks around the authentication process. You will have to hack digest support in, then. Alternatively, use an HTTP proxy that does the Digest authentication for you.

Answer (score 0):

no, libtorrent does not support digest authentication for HTTP seeds.

Patches are welcome! (and really, web servers and HTTP trackers should really be transitioned to use `boost.beast` instead of a homegrown HTTP parser)